# How to change the color of Pined controlbar in Shiny Dashboard

Tags: css, r, shiny, styles, shinydashboard

Looking for a way to change the color of the pinned controlbar in shinyDashboard. I have been able to change the color of every element in the shinydashboard except for the little pin when you pin the controlbar on the right side of main page.
Any Help would be highly appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(),
    controlbar = dashboardControlbar(
      id = "controlbar",
      collapsed = FALSE,
      overlay = TRUE, 
      skin = "light",
      pinned = T
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
  }
)
```

[image]

Comment: you need to change the color of an icon

Comment: Thanks @Aman Sharma, can you add it it the simple code chunk I included in this post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the thumb-tack color, you can use

```
tags$head(tags$style(type = "text/css", ".fa-thumbtack {color:rgb(255,0,0)  !important;}"))
```

Full code

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(
      #tags$style(".fa-thumbtack {color:rgb(255,0,0)}"), ##  this changes only the horizontal pin color
      tags$head(tags$style(type = "text/css", ".fa-thumbtack {color:rgb(255,0,0)  !important;}"))
    ),
    controlbar = dashboardControlbar(
      id = "controlbar",
      collapsed = FALSE,
      overlay = TRUE, 
      skin = "light",
      pinned = T
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks, @YBS, your solution resolved my question. By chance, do you know how to change the color for the vertical pin only?

Comment: No.  You should play with CSS to try and figure out.